# Accessing attached artifacts from a Maven Mojo

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin which has a zip file attached as an artifact. As a part of the mojo execution, I need to unpack the zip file and execute a binary inside it, but I cannot figure out how to obtain a reference to the `Artifact` representing the attached artifact. I can do like this:

```
    Artifact rpcgenArtifact = factory.createArtifactWithClassifier(
            "com.iar", "iar-codegen-plugin", "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT", "zip",
            "rpcgen-linux");
    resolver.resolve(rpcgenArtifact,
            project.getRemoteArtifactRepositories(), localRepository);

    getLog().info(rpcgenArtifact.getFile().toString());
```

which will work, but I would like to avoid hardcoding the name/version of the Mojo inside itself. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your `mojo` can include these co-ordinates as configurable parameters using the `<configuration>` tag. Also, I think `ArtifactFactory` is deprecated since `m3`; so consider using the `Aether`'s `RepositorySystem`.